# Calling a C++ library from Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8, interop

I want to call into a C++ library that wasn't originally compiled on Windows from a Windows Phone 8 application.  Is this possible?  How do I create a Windows Runtime component to wrap my C++ objects?  How can this be done?  I don't want to have to recompile using managed C++ if I don't need to.  Thanks in advance.